# ViewExpiredException when accesing site via googlebot

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, googlebot

On my JSF page (Primefaces) googlebot is causing ViewExpiredException when accessing site. It happens only on POST requests (invalid javax.faces.ViewState?).

I'm running on Wildfly 9.0.1.Final, Primefaces 5.3

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.resourceUpdateCheckPeriod</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge</param-name>
    <param-value>3628800000</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.SUBMIT</param-name>
    <param-value>partial</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>native</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.primefaces.extensions.DELIVER_UNCOMPRESSED_RESOURCES</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.primefaces.extensions.WRAP_PRIME_FACES_RESOURCES</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.ocpsoft.rewrite.annotation.BASE_PACKAGES</param-name>
    <param-value>pl.izen.carmen.rewrite</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
      <param-value>51200</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.RewriteServletRequestListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.RewriteServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>OCPsoft Rewrite Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>pl.izen.carmen.custom.servlet.IzenRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OCPsoft Rewrite Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Public Images Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.izen.carmen.servlets.images.PublicImagesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Public Images Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/public_images/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Product Images Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.izen.carmen.servlets.images.ProductsImageServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Product Images Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/product/image/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CKEditorUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.izen.carmen.servlets.images.CKEditorUploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CKEditorUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ckeditor/upload/uploadimage</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PrimePushServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
      <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.atmosphere.annotation.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>org.primefaces.push</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>pl.izen.push</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PrimePushServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <!--  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy JSAPI</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.jsapi.JSAPIServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy JSAPI</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest-js</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CeneoServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ceneo/servlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>CeneoServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CeneoServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.izen.carmen.custom.integration.ceneo.CeneoServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HeurekaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/heureka/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>HeurekaServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>HeurekaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.izen.carmen.custom.integration.heureka.HeurekaServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MerchantServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/merchant/servlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>MerchantServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MerchantServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.izen.carmen.custom.integration.google.GoogleMerchantServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SitemapXmlServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.izen.carmen.custom.servlet.SitemapXmlServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SitemapXmlServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sitemap.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RobotsTxtServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.izen.carmen.custom.servlet.RobotsTxtServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RobotsTxtServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/robots.txt</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>start.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>administrator</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>CSS</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>CSS</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>SitemapXmlServlet</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/sitemap.xml</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>RobotsTxtServlet</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/robots.txt</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Unsecured application frontend - object page</web-resource-name>
      <description>Objects</description>
      <url-pattern>/pages/seoObject.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>login.xhtml</web-resource-name>
      <description>Unprotect login.xhtml</description>
      <url-pattern>/login.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Public resources</web-resource-name>
      <description>All visible resources</description>
      <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>All resources</web-resource-name>
      <description>Protects all resources</description>
      <url-pattern>/pages/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
      <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>All resources</web-resource-name>
      <description>Protects all resources</description>
      <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
      <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>All resources</web-resource-name>
      <description>Protects all resources</description>
      <url-pattern>/index.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
      <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Public Images Servlet</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/public_images/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Unsecured application frontend</web-resource-name>
      <description>Start page</description>
      <url-pattern>/start.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
      <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
  </session-config>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/error_500.xhtml</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>408</error-code>
    <location>/error/error_408.xhtml</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error/error_404.xhtml</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/error_404.xhtml</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error/error.xhtml</location>
  </error-page>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>secure</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
      <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>ico</extension>
    <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Almost all components im using are @ViewScoped (CDI), I'm not using @ConversationScoped components.
As You can see in web.xml I'm also using rewrite-filter with primepush (both are working just fine).

Request that is causing error:

```
X-FORWARDED-FROM: 66.249.79.135
METHOD: POST
PARAM: viewUrl => some_product_name
PARAM: commands:j_idt55 => commands:j_idt55
PARAM: javax.faces.ViewState => 1802363348692608902:3687015195185271050
PARAM: width => 1024
PARAM: javax.faces.source => commands:j_idt55
PARAM: javax.faces.partial.ajax => true
PARAM: javax.faces.partial.execute => @all
PARAM: commands => commands
PARAM: height => 1024
```

Edit:
It's happenig mostly on one page which uses additional param (viewUrl) which decides what product will be shown. This is a GET param but googlebot uses POST method. On this page user can add product to cart or rate it, nothing else.

GET requests from crawlers (google too) are working fine.

Edit2:
I observed that I got same exception when doing POST navigation (faces-redirect=true) but when I changed com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews to 100 exception is not being thrown anymore. Why JSF is constructing so many views?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Haven't seen this before. Does this happen on specific commands/forms only, or is this arbitrary? If specific, what do those commands represent? Page-to-page navigation or genuine data entry forms?

Comment: I'm using h:link for navigation but i'll check entire project maybe I'm missing something. Thanx for helping BalusC, if i find anwser i'll post it here. I'm stariting to think that You are JSF God... :)

Comment: It seems that com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews is too low, anyone know what can cause this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After a long time I found the cause. Google bot is cachig site and from some time has possiblity of firing posts requests on cached sites. It seems it was firing **primefaces remote commads** with old *JSF ViewId*. And that was the issue.